# ng-Grid columns stacked or not displaying properly

Tags: angularjs, stacked, ng-grid

I am trying to display sample data in a ng-grid via AngularJS. Everything looks correct to me. If I pass 'ngGrid' in the module definition within my local project the columns are getting stacked one below the other. I tried doing this in plunker , but it's not rendering properly.

Here is the sample code.

http://plnkr.co/edit/AHQUjbus908HBLxUaIWr

Comment: Well, your plunker has errors (You're not including libraries properly).

Comment: Which libraries are required besides NG-Grid.js, angular.js and jQuery? Can you please help clarify ?

Comment: Never mind. I got what you're saying. We having the correct version of libraries made it to work. - Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the references to the external nggrid files.  A lot of times referencing github files doesn't work very well.  I've moved the nggrid js and css into local plunkr files and forked your plunkr.  It now works.

http://plnkr.co/edit/N5T0Ys3Fc58NymAvzMFj?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
minWidth: 50,
width: '*'
```

in you columnDefs like,

```
{
field: 'severity',
displayName: 'Severity',
resizable: true,
minWidth: 50,
width: '*'
}
```

It worked for me.